# How to fit Werthamer-Helfand-Hohenberg (WHH) equation in a $H_{c2}$ vs $T$ equation?

Tags: superconductivity

The Werthamer-Helfand-Hohenberg (WHH) formula $$μ_0H_{c2}(0)=0.693μ_0T_c\frac{dH_{c2}}{dT}|T→Tc$$
was used to estimate μ$_0$H$_c$2(0) at 0 K where only orbital breaking effects are considered in the dirty limit. In various research articles this equation has been fitted with experimental $H_{c2}$ vs T. How can this equation be fitted? My understanding is $$\frac{dH_{c2}}{dT}|T→Tc$$ is a number, so instead of getting many numbers [which is required to fit this equation] i will get only one number. Kindly help me in this.

For reference https://journals.aps.org/prmaterials/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.3.024802

Answer (score 0):

For fitting the WHH model, you will have to use their general equation, with the spin-orbit and maki parameters used as fitting parameters. This has been used by many authors for determining the Hc2 for superconductors in the dirty limit. The equation typically looks like this:

$$\ln\frac{1}{t}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\lambda_{\rm so}}{4\gamma}\right)\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\bar{h}+\lambda_{\rm so}/2+i\gamma}{2t}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\lambda_{\rm so}}{4\gamma}\right)\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\bar{h}+\lambda_{\rm so}/2-i\gamma}{2t}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

With $\psi$ being the digamma function. I highly recommend reading this paper by Toyota et al. for further details on the fit: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00681771